# Is that a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I came across the question if
`f(x) = x + y` ($x$ and $y$ are vectors)
is a linear transformation.

I would answer that this is not a linear transformation because if y would be anything else than the zero vector then for $x =$ zero vector, the resulting vector would not be the zero vector and thus, the origin would not stay in place.

But if $y$ would be the zero vector, would this count as a linear transformation?

Thanks

Comment: If $y=\vec 0$ then $f(x)=x$ is just the identity map, which is certainly linear.  For non-zero $y$, your argument is correct,  Linear maps must preserve $\vec 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $f(x+x') = (x+x')+y = x+x'+y$, but $f(x)+f(x') = (x+y)+(x'+y) = x+x' +2y$.

So unless $y=0$, $f(x+x') \ne f(x)+f(x')$ and hence $f$ is not a linear transformation.

Comment: Can you maybe explain your answer a little more, please?

Comment: if $f$ is linear then $f(x+x') = f(x)+f(x')$

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ you defined is called a ***translation** of step* $y$, where $y$ is a vector. Some textbooks write translations as $t_y(x) = x+y$, where both $x$ and $y$ are vectors.

Yes, you're right: unless $y$ is the zero vector, $f$  is not a linear transformation. I will tell you more: since this is indeed a translation, you can also prove that the only translation which is also a linear transformation, is the translation by the zero vector, which is nothing more but the identity.
$$t_y \; \text{is a linear transformation} \iff y=\vec{0}$$